# Window like command prompt in python

Tags: wxpython

I need a window in python like a command prompt to run ssh client program in windows os. I just need a window to accept user input and show output like command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a widget like that. I would just create a text control or two to accept the user's input and then a button to run it. If you use subprocess, you might be able to use the process that's explained in this article to redirect the output to your program:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/05/python-running-ping-traceroute-and-more/

Or you might need to take a look at the wx.PyOnDemandOutputWindow class.